# You cannot alter to or from m2m fields or add or remove through =onmn2m fields

Tags: django

What is this error:
You cannot alter to or from m2m fields or add or remove through=on m2m fields

```
Class post(models.Model):
 Title=models.CharField(max_length=50)

Class cat_child(midels.Model):
 name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
 post=models.ManyToManyField(Post)
 cat_parent=models.ForeignKey('Cat_Parent',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Class cat_parent(models.Model):
```

name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

Why is that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* ([I downvoted because there is no code](//idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Why do you need an intermediate table if all you're doing is creating a standard ManyToMany relationship? (Django creates the intermediate table automatically for you, without you having to write any code)

Comment: I'd suggest you read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Are you looking for a [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)?

Comment: Hey bro. U know about this error?

Answer (score -2):

Django by default creates an intermediate table, but if you want to specify one manually you must do through through ManyToManyField (referring to the intermediate table)

```
class Category(models.Model):
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    post=models.ManyToMany(Post, through='PostCat')
```

and Then specify the intermediate table as it did.

The only change would be to add the `through = 'PostCat'` in ManyToMany where PosCat is the intermediate table referenced.

You can find more in the documentation, but basically that is the solution:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/

Comment: What about through_field? Is that necessary?

Comment: It is necessary as long as you decide to customize your own intermediate model and through that through_field you specify that model. And in your case, it's what you're looking for, right?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks bro.